# Map.lookup strange behavior with typing

Tags: haskell, types

I have been using Map.lookup in Haskell and I am constantly getting the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]` with actual type `Maybe String`.
```

Is there a quick and simple way to convert this?

Comment: Folks here can help you better if can show your code which reproduces the above error.

Comment: Note that `String` is an alias of `[Char]`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, there's no way to say for sure, but most likely you've looked something up in a `Map` and expected to get a `String` (which is the same as `[Char]`). In fact, `lookup` returns a `Maybe String`, so it can return `Nothing` if the requested key is not in the `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "convert" `x :: Maybe String` to a `String`, unless you decide how to handle the case where `x` is `Nothing` -- in your case, when the element in the `Map` was not found.

Try something like this:

```
case Map.lookup ... of
   Nothing  -> ... -- handle the "not found" case
   Just str -> ... -- handle the "found" case, str contains the found string value
```

There's also a [maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe) function which can provide a shorter alternative in some cases, but I'd recommend learning how to use a `case` first.

Comment: I'd like point out to beginners that this highlights one of the best things about Haskell. Haskell forces the programmer to think about the non-happy path up front and handle it explicitly. This is counter to most other programming languages, but it leads to much more reliable programs.